Is it possible to replicate the behavior of \NewDocumentCommand in KaTeX
I am working on a React project where I need to replicate the behavior of the \NewDocumentCommand in KaTeX. As an example, I'd like to replicate the following LaTeX command definition:
\NewDocumentCommand{\nder}{ m O{} O{x}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}.
This command allows for optional parameters with default values.
In a first attempt, I added "\\nder": String.raw`\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}`  to the options.macros object in the katex.render. Even though it works, it isn't enough as it doesn't account for optional parameters and doesn't contemplate their default values.
The KaTeX's options documentation does mention that each property of macros may have as a value either a string, a function or a MacroExpansion object, which gives me hope that it might be possible to replicate the command. However, the documentation is too technical for me to grasp fully.
I would greatly appreciate any advice from someone familiar with the KaTeX codebase on how to handle optional parameters with default values in custom macros.
